# How to forbid Chrome from opening a new tab (via onclick)?

Tags: google-chrome

Sometimes, when I click a link it will open a new tab. Is there a way to forbid Chrome from doing so?

Steps to produce the problem.

- Go to http://useast.ensembl.org/biomart
- On the "CHOOSE DATABASE" drop-down list, choose any database
- On the "CHOOSE DATASET" drop-down list, choose any dataset
- Click "Results" on the top left.
- Click "Go" on the top right. -> A new tab will be create and once the file is downloaded the tab will be closed.

Comment: Too complicated. I'd suppose there may be an option of chrome to change. There is no such an option?

Comment: If there was an option you could find it yourself, or we'd tell you.

Comment: No. For my problem, there is no such target="_blank". See the update.